# How to avoid the erf(x)?

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

I need to solve the following integral:

$$x\int\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{x^2}\,dx$$

I'm told that by using the Taylor expansion of $e^z$ and "integrating term by term" show that it's equal to:

$$\alpha x + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n(2n-1)n!}x^{2n}.$$

Really not sure what to do.

Comment: why is the $x$ before the integral? what is the meaning of that?

Comment: there is an $x$ before the integral in the question. The whole integral appears to be multiplied by $x$ for some reason.

Comment: Also what is with the title?When did you get erf?

Comment: the solution containes the error function

Comment: $$\int\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^2}\,dx = - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}erf\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x} + C$$

Comment: @M.Turner First replace $e^{-x^2/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2/2)^n}{n!}$ then integrate the sum term by term.

Comment: Ohh yes, That helped a lot! I think I've shown it now. Thank you.